# select xml rows without column header in SQL Server FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a table with rows of valid XML nodes (one column, xml type) that looks like this:

```
create table #t (x xml not null);
insert into #t
values ('<service><value1>stuff</value1><value2>more stuff</value2></service>')
, ('<service><value1>I am a different row</value1><value2>more stuff</value2></service>');
```

I would like to select these into one XML blob:

```
<services>
  <service>. . .</service>
  <service>. . .</service>
</services>
```

I am using FOR XML PATH to try this, but it embeds the column header "x" as a node around the "service" nodes.

```
select x
from #t
for XML PATH(''), ROOT('services')
```

This produces:

```
<services>
  <x><service>. . .</service></x>
  <x><service>. . .</service></x>
</services>
```

How can I get rid of the "x" node?

I tried select x as "" and select x as "." but these are reserved words, and the query errors out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
 select x.query('*')
 from   #t
 for xml path(''), root('services')
```